# How to pass the submit form data to a pop up window

Tags: javascript, forms, popup, submit, anchor

I made a form for user to type in their input , then , i want to pass this input to another page and display the new page in a pop up window.
Here is what I code :

This is the input page:

```
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);$('#form1').submit();" onclick="window.open('${req.contextPath}/secure/Graph.jspa','popup','width=800,height=800');return false;" >Graph</a></li>
        <li >
            <form id="form1" method="post" action="${req.contextPath}/secure/Graph.jspa">
                <input type="text"
                       id="myfirstparameter"
                       name="myfirstparameter"
                       value="$textutils.htmlEncode(${myfirstparameter})"

                />
        </li>
```

Then in the display page :

```
<p>The raw current parameter value is: $action.getMyfirstparameter() </p>
```

So after click the anchor link Graph. It should pop up a new page to display user's input. but for my code , it didnt show the user input , it show the default value in stead.

If i remove the pop-up function ( which is onclick="window.open......) , it will run correctly , however , there is no pop up .
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer . thanks . This is the ans for anyone who need, you need to add the windown,open in the  instead :

```
target="DoSubmit" onsubmit="DoSubmit = window.open('about:blank','DoSubmit','width=400,height=350');"
```

reference : http://agichevski.com/2013/08/17/submit-form-into-popup-window-using-javascript/